# Pattern matching in C , Alternative to pcre

Tags: c, pcre

I am trying to write a C code that will find hyperlinks in a mail and replace them.
Is using a pcre library a good thing to do ? 
Since pcre is ,allegedly, too slow  is there an alternative ?

Comment: Use an HTML parser to parse HTML. That is what they are for.

Comment: @Mat He could also mean bare URLs in the body of a plaintext email. (Or he might not, this should be clarified.)

Comment: I agree with @Inerdial; "too slow" needs a lot of context to be a meaningful judgement.

Comment: Check out this benchmark of Regex Libraries: http://lh3lh3.users.sourceforge.net/reb.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is the *last* language I would choose to do this.  Firstly, if you want to do this with high accuracy - use a MIME parser to get the HTML body out.  Java has mime4j, Perl has MIME::Parser, Python has email, etc.  This isn't too hard and I'm willing to help with this step in any of these languages if you'd like.  Secondly, use an HTML parser to isolate the links.

If you're ok with some mistakes then just write a one-line program in Perl or PHP.  Or sed even.  Really.  If you are replacing with a fixed URL, use sed.  If you are modifying the URL, the only reason this won't work as-is is you'll probably have to url_encode it which a P-language can handle in one line.

Comment: Totally agree. You have to choose the right tool for the problem, not using only the tool you know for all problems.

Comment: What's a "P-Language"? Perl/Python/PHP?

Comment: hammers are for nails and screwdrivers are for screws ! You may do it very fast and very well with C, but with more line of code, and statistically more bugs. A higher level language will do the same job, faster and easily. (btw, if you only need to change URIs in mails, sed in a shell might as well work :) )

Comment: Correct, I would not have chosen to write it in C too. I am a perl programmer myself. But the problem is this has to be a part of a milter see https://www.milter.org/.  Milters are only supported in C .. there are perl ports but they crash in production.

Comment: Is C++ an option?  It's definitely better than C and links into it.

Comment: Not C++ either. Wietse , the autor of postfix recommends writing milters in C only. I think PCRE would be fast enough seeing the benchmarks posted in this thread. 

Is there a sample code I can see on how to do substitutions using PCRE .. In perl it is just a simple 

--------------
my $dbh = DBI->connect( ...)
...
s/($LINK_REGEX)/\&get_link($dbh,$1)/sge;
---------------
How can I do an equivalent in PCRE